# How do I line up columns horizontally?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap 3 page which has 4 wells on it. Each well has a different amount of data, and its causing the layout to look fairly bad.

I would like to get the 3rd and 4th wells to line up under wells 1 and 2. I don't mind the spaces that will exist between the top and bottom of the wells.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="well well-sm">
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend class="well-legend">Well 1</legend>
                        <p>Well 1 Content</p>
                        <p>Well 1 Content</p>
                        <p>Well 1 Content</p>
                        <p>Well 1 Content</p>
                        <p>Well 1 Content</p>
                        <p>Well 1 Content</p>
                        <p>Well 1 Content</p>

                    </fieldset>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="well well-sm">
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend class="well-legend">Well 2</legend>
                        <p>Well 2 Content</p>
                        <p>Well 2 Content</p>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="well well-sm">
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend class="well-legend">Well 3</legend>
                            <p>Well 3 Content</p>
                            <p>Well 3 Content</p>
                            <p>Well 3 Content</p>
                            <p>Well 3 Content</p>
                            <p>Well 3 Content</p>
                            <p>Well 3 Content</p>
                            <p>Well 3 Content</p>
                            <p>Well 3 Content</p>
                            <p>Well 3 Content</p>
                            <p>Well 3 Content</p>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="well well-sm">
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend class="well-legend">Well 4</legend>
                            Well 4 Content
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Bootply Link](http://www.bootply.com/giFX58N05D)

Answer (score 2):

If this is what you want, then I think you may need to change from the fluid containers you are using and just use:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
```

Comment: +1 this seems to work. See updated [**bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/N9NA0s1Cfx)

Comment: Yup, works great. Here's a fork of that, cleaned up the alignment a bit more. [link](http://www.bootply.com/3yRnYsDFgU)